# I am trying to modify some content in text file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to modify some content in text file using regular expression in perl script its not modifying anything but when i use the same regular expresion in textpad it modifies

input

```
    ab 3fdfs2sd 6 Feb 2015.doc Creatings som junk text: ccpsd(1).xml.
    sdfdgd .df . fds  18 Mar 2015.doc  Creatings som junk text: ccpsd(2).xml.
```

output requried:

```
    ccpsd(1).xml-ab 3fdfs2sd 6 Feb 2015.xml
    ccpsd(2).xml-sdfdgd .df . fds  18 Mar 2015.xml
```

code

```
    use strict;
    open(FILE, "<G:/in.txt") || die "File not found";
     my @lines = <FILE>;  
     close(FILE);

    my @newlines;
    foreach(@lines) {

       $_ =~ s/(^.+?)\.doc\s*.+?[\:]\s*(CC.+?xml)\./\2-\1.xml/igs;

          push(@newlines,$_);
    }

    open(FILE, ">/out.txt") || die "File not found";
    print FILE @newlines;
    close(FILE);
```

Comment: What do you have in out.txt? It works for me, except you have to use `$1` and `$2` instead of `\1` and `\2`. You must also `use warnings;` at the begining of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double `>>` and specify file name:

```
my $outfile = 'out.txt';
open (FILE, ">> $outfile") || die "File not found";
```

The regex is fine, as tested in this [sample program](http://goo.gl/SBmo2Y).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have missed the Drive for the output file.
I'd do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file  = 'G:/in.txt';
my $out_file = 'G:/out.txt';

open my $in, '<', $in_file or die "Unable to open '$in_file': $!";
open my $out, '>', $out_file or die "Unable to open '$out_file': $!";
while(<$in>) {
    chomp;
    s/^(.+?)\.doc\s*.+?:\s*(CC.+?xml)\./$2-$1.xml/i;
    print $out $_,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Perl one-liner

```
perl -pe's/(^.+?)\.doc\s*.+?[\:]\s*(CC.+?xml)\./\2-\1.xml/ig'
```

BTW Did you read [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#s) and are you sure you understand it? Because you read your input file by lines and `s` modifier in your code doesn't make any sense. If you really want to apply regexp for multiline pattern, you should use.

```
perl -0777 -pe's/(^.+?)\.doc\s*.+?[\:]\s*(CC.+?xml)\./\2-\1.xml/igs'
```